# Yakuake window not at top in KDE

Tags: kde, plasma5

I've configrued my Yakuake window to open from the top, but when I press the shortcut the window occasionally appears in the middle of my screen. How can I get it to always appear on top?[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems to be caused by Wayland, after restarting the session with X11 it was positioned properly. That's the only workaround I found.

I tried window rules (systemsettings > workspace > window management) first, but the window itself seems to think it is at the top of the screen. If you use the detect window properties feature, it will give you a position at the top of the screen: 78x32 for me, because I have my panel at the top.